# Check if WebSphere server is up

Tags: linux, ssh, java, putty

Is it possible to check from Java code whether a Linux server (websphere) is up or not?

I use the command below (from Java with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`) in order to open SSH session to my Websphere server. I want to run the `ServerStatus.sh` script which is located under the `bin` directory and return the indicator about the server status.

```
putty.exe -t -ssh userName@serverName -pw userPassword -P 22
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Putty comes with command-line version, [`plink.exe`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). You can give it the command to execute on the remote end as argument and will get it's output on standard output.
2. You can use the `ssh` client from openssh, probably via MSys. Unlike Windows-specific `plink`, this exists on all platforms.
3. Or you can use some SSH library for Java. [Some suggestions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java) This is probably the best option since you won't be dependent on external tools being installed.